# Creating a static collection to store values in java

Tags: java, collections, static

How do I store objects in this particular *collection* type? Do I have to create a method or constructor? I have seen different examples of creating array lists but not this type of array list. What does the `static` imply, does it mean only for the class `Inventory`?

```
static List<Inventory> values = new ArrayList<Inventory>();
```

---

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Inventory {
    static List<Inventory> values = new ArrayList<Inventory>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `List<Inventory>` means a `List` for holding `Inventory` instances. You can add, and later iterate, elements to your `values`. Because it is `static`, there is only one per class. Finally, because there is no specified access modifier, it is only accessible to classes in the same package (that is the default is *package private*). In Java 7+, this

```
static List<Inventory> values = new ArrayList<Inventory>();
```

can be shortened to

```
static List<Inventory> values = new ArrayList<>();
```

As for adding methods (and fields), yes you will need those to do anything really useful. For a simple example, you might have a value field<sup>**1**</sup> and assign it some value in the constructor. Then you could populate your `values` and finally iterate<sup>**2**</sup> them to display something

```
int aValue;
public Inventory(int value) {
    this.aValue = value;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    values.add(new Inventory(1));
    values.add(new Inventory(2));
    for (Inventory v : values) { // <-- a for-each loop
        System.out.println(v.aValue);
    }
}
```

<sup>**1**<sub>Hence `aValue`.</sub></sup>

<sup>**2**<sub>Here I used a [`for-each`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop.</sub></sup>

Comment: so if i wanted to add values to the array would it be values.add("hi"); @ElliottFrisch

Comment: @MikeShasaco See edit. The only way it would be `values.add("hi");` is if `values` was a `List<String>` (because `"hi"` is a `String`).